# Get Last modified date on Blob Storage

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

I'm uploading a file into Azure Storage Explorer, the blob check every 12 hours for a file, if there is a file an email is sent. When an email is sent I need to get the time and date when the file is uploaded not when the email is sent. I use the `List of Files LastModified` and the output is like this `2021-09-22T15:15:55Z`, I don't need the time in UTC. Is there any way to change convert the time using the `List of Files LastModified`?

Comment: is your issue resolved?

Comment: @CXLSX, in what format do you need the time? How would you expect "2021-09-22T15:15:55Z" to be presented?

Comment: Hi, my expectations are "2021-09-22" instead of the whole datetime.

Answer (score 1):

The 'List of Files LastModified' gives the exact thing that you required while in order to change the utc to local/Any time zone that we required, we need to add a function 'convertFromUtc'.

For CST :

```
formatDateTime(convertTimeZone(utcNow(), 'UTC', 'Central Standard Time'),'HH:mm:ss')
```

For IST:

```
formatDateTime(convertTimeZone(utcNow(), 'UTC', 'India Standard Time'),'HH:mm:ss')
```

else you can perform hardcoded operation such as to [SubtractFromTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/adaptive-expressions/subtractfromtime?view=botbuilder-ts-latest) or [AddToTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/adaptive-expressions/addtotime?view=botbuilder-ts-latest) considering the timezone that we wanted.

Here is the flow of my logic app
[image]

[image]

[image]

REFERENCES :
[Reference guide for functions in expressions - Azure Logic Apps | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#converttimezone)